# Conda in cmd doesn't behave as in conda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I recently updated conda to the latest version and while it works flawlessly on the conda prompt:

[image]

it doesn't seem to work when i launch conda from a cmd window:

[image]

What i notice is the conda version is still the old one and that the base environment is not the same from the conda prompt.

all my previous environments, while being displayed with their paths are now nameless.

This is unexpected because it used to work fine with the old conda version and i would get the same behavior form conda prompt in the cmd... (which is practical to run code from IDE's)

I am a bit lost and was wondering whether anyone encoutered the problem before.

Ideally i would have the updated conda, work in cmd the same way as in conda prompt

Comment: Open the properties of your Anaconda Prompt (right click from the start menu > Properties), please check what path it is running, and run the same command in normal cmd, it will behave exact same. The issue is now you have more than one installation, but your System Path still points to old folder